# How to center the text for the toggle switch

Tags: html, css

I have a pricing plan page that I am trying to add a toggle switch to. I can't seem to figure out the proper way to vertically align the text of it: [here is my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g01hd3Ln/1/)

I've tried to set the margin and the padding but the Monthly and Annual are always at the top.

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="toggle-btn" style="background-color:transparent;text-align:center;position:relative;z-index:99;vertical-align:top;">
      <span style="margin:0.8em;color:rgb(44, 46, 47);font-size:18px;bottom:0px;">Monthly</span>
      <label class="switch" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checbox" onclick="check()" />
        <span class="slider round"></span>
      </label>
      <span style="margin:0.8em;color:rgb(44, 46, 47);font-size:18px;bottom:0px;">Annual&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="panel pricing-table">

      <div class="pricing-plan">
        <img src="https://s22.postimg.cc/8mv5gn7w1/paper-plane.png" alt="" class="pricing-img">
        <h2 class="pricing-header">Personal</h2>
        <ul class="pricing-features">
          <li class="pricing-features-item">Custom domains</li>
          <li class="pricing-features-item">Sleeps after 30 mins of inactivity</li>
        </ul>
        <span class="pricing-price">Free</span>
        <a href="#/" class="pricing-button">Sign up</a>
      </div>

      <div class="pricing-plan">
        <img src="https://s28.postimg.cc/ju5bnc3x9/plane.png" alt="" class="pricing-img">
        <h2 class="pricing-header">Small team</h2>
        <ul class="pricing-features">
          <li class="pricing-features-item">Never sleeps</li>
          <li class="pricing-features-item">Multiple workers for more powerful apps</li>
        </ul>
        <span class="pricing-price">$150</span>
        <a href="#/" class="pricing-button is-featured">Free trial</a>
      </div>

      <div class="pricing-plan">
        <img src="https://s21.postimg.cc/tpm0cge4n/space-ship.png" alt="" class="pricing-img">
        <h2 class="pricing-header">Enterprise</h2>
        <ul class="pricing-features">
          <li class="pricing-features-item">Dedicated</li>
          <li class="pricing-features-item">Simple horizontal scalability</li>
        </ul>
        <span class="pricing-price">$400</span>
        <a href="#/" class="pricing-button">Free trial</a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `margin-bottom` from that switch element and add `display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;` to `.toggle-btn`

Here's the edited fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bjd3wps1/

Answer (score 1):

you just had to add `position: relative` to the spans containing the text and than update the bottom value to `bottom: -5px`

here's the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a2nwet54/